# Table formatting, Arrangement of cells. Business Model Canvas

Tags: tables

I'm trying to have a "*[Business Model Canvas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Model_Canvas#/media/File:Business_Model_Canvas.png)*" -table within a XeLaTeX environment in an Overleaf document. However, the cells in the last two rows do not arrange as specified (planned: image 1; result: image 2), (Cells with number representing headlines, empty cells are for content)
Also I would like the column groups, when filled with content, evenly distributed as in image 1.

I'm an absolute latex beginner. What am I doing wrong?

I used *tablesgenerator.com* for the table code.

Thank you in advance!

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{0}                                                                 \\ \hline
1                 & 2 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{3}} & 4 & 5                 \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{5-6} 
\multirow{3}{*}{} &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                   &   & \multirow{3}{*}{} \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{5-5}
                  & 6 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                   & 7 &                   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{5-5}
                  &   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                   &   &                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{8}                    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{9}                     \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}                     & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356667/width-of-columns-in-a-table-with-only-multicolumns

Comment: Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document starting with `\documenrclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Power of used  `tablesgenerator` is not sufficient for writting a table as you like to have, consequently the columns in the last two rows collapse. Try the folloowing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setcellgapes{1em}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{ |*{6}{w{c}{2em}|} }
    \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{0} \\ 
    \hline
1   & 2 & \multicolumn{2}{w{c}{\dimexpr4em+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{3}
                & 4 & 5         \\
    \hline
    &   &   \multicolumn{2}{w{c}{\dimexpr4em+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{}
                &   &           \\ 
    \cline{2-2} \cline{5-5}
    & 6 & \multicolumn{2}{w{c}{\dimexpr4em+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{}               
            & 7 &                   \\ 
    \cline{2-2} \cline{5-5}
    &   &   \multicolumn{2}{w{c}{\dimexpr4em+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|}{}
                &   &           \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|w{c}{\dimexpr6em+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}|}{8}
                & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{9} \\ 
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. In that environment, similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`), you can merge cells both vertically and horizontally with the command `\Block`. The key `hvlines` draws all the rules, excepted in the blocks.

Since `nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns of the array, it's possible to use those nodes to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz.

Here, I have drawn the vertical rule in the middle of the last two rows with Tikz (with an instruction in the `\CodeAfter` of the environment).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccw{c}{1cm}cc}[hvlines]
  \Block{1-*}{0} \\
              1 & 2 & \Block{4-1}{3} & 4 & 5             \\
  \Block{3-1}{} &   &                &   & \Block{3-1}{} \\
                & 6 &                & 7 &               \\
  \\
  \Block{1-*}{} % to prevent the vertical rules in that row 
                & 8 &                & 9 \\              
  \Block{1-*}{} % to prevent the vertical rules in that row 
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (6-|3.5) -- (8-|3.5) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: **Remark with Overleaf**. Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`